# How to draw an amount of circles in pygame from a database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pygame

I have database made in Sqlite3 and i read the file and get all users from the database then i want to draw a circle for each user. so if there are three users i want to draw three cicles about 100 pixels apart from each other. So far this is what I have:

```
with sqlite3.connect("root\\Users.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
data = cursor.fetchall()
an = len(data)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    screen.fill(white)
    for i in range(an):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (dc,250), 77, 1)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Do you want to draw all circles in a row? Then just use `i * some_value` as the x-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I would change your

```
for i in range(an):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (dc, 250), 77, 1)
```

to

```
offset = 100 # change offset to whatever you want the offset to be
for i in range(an):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (i*offset, 250), 77, 1)
```

however, I would keep in mind that this code is from the center of the circle to the center of the next circle. To make it so that the circle would have 100px from their edges you would have to add your circle's radius to the offset variable. That would look like:

```
    radius = 77
    offset = 100 + (2*radius) # change offset to whatever you want the offset to be

    for i in range(an):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (i*offset, 250), 77, 1)
```